# How to reuse a field created into a pipeline stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I use the aggregation framework of MongoDb for complex search. 
Regarding the context, a central structure, named profiles, references a lot of substructure (e.g. user, location, etc.). Regarding the search, I would to reuse a field declared in the entry 'as' of stage $lookup. But, I don't find how do that.
There is an example :

```
db.profiles.aggregate([{$lookup: {
    from: "users",
    'let': { userId: "$userId" },
    pipeline: [{
        $match: {
            $expr: {$and: [
                {$gte:["$_age",40]},
                {$lte:["$_age",50]},
                {$eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"]}
            ]}
        }
    }],
    as: "user"}},
    { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ { $size: "$$user" }, 1 ] },
           then: "$$DESCEND",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }}]);
```

I get the following error message :

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: user",
"code" : 17276,
"codeName" : "Location17276"
```

or

```
"errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
```

So, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are using the $$ that is used for referencing user variables. So just use $user in the redact stage. In fact, you dont need redact at all. you can just use `{$match:{"user.0":{$exists:true}}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Veeram
It works and your answer inspire me. 
This one works too : {$match:{$expr: {$eq: [{$size:"$user"},1]}}

Comment: The usage of $ depends on the used operator and effective position into the definition.